# Split a string by comma, quote and full-stop.. with a few exceptions

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I've got a lot of text, similar to the following paragraph, which I'd like to split into words without punctuation (`'`, `"`, `,`, `.`, `newline` etc).. with a few exceptions.

> Initially considered endemic to the Chalakudy River system in Kerala state, southern India, but now recognised to have a wider distribution in surrounding drainages including the Periyar, Manimala, and Pamba river though the Manimala data may be questionable given it seems to be the type locality of P. denisonii.
>
> In the Achankovil River basin it occurs sympatrically, and sometimes syntopically, with P. denisonii.
>
> Wild stocks may have dwindled by as much as 50% in the last 15 years or so with collection for the aquarium trade largely held responsible although habitats are also being degraded by pollution from agricultural and domestic sources, plus destructive fishing methods involving explosives or organic toxins.

The text refers to `P. denisonii` which is a species of fish. It's an abbreviation of `Genus species`. I would like this reference to be one word.

So, for instance, this is the kind of array I'd like to see:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [44] given
    [45] it
    [46] seems
    [47] to
    [48] be
    [49] the
    [50] type
    [51] locality
    [52] of
    [53] P. denisonii
    [54] In
    [55] the
    ...
)
```

The only things that distinguish these species references such as `P. denisonii` from a new sentence like `end. New` are:

- **The P** (for Puntius, as in the P. in the aforementioned example) **is only ever one letter, always a capital**
- **the d** (as in . denisonii) **is always either a lower case letter or an apostrophe (`'`)**

What regexp can I use with `preg_split` to give me such an array? I've tried a simple `explode( " ", $array )` but it doesn't do the job at all.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You could do the splitting with `explode` and `str_replace`, but I'm not sure about the `P. denisonii`...

Answer (score 2):

Change your approach: why not use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_split`?
Instead of splitting the text with splitting delimiters, you'll match all the strings that *do not* contain the delimiters.

Use it with a regexp like: `/([\S]+)|(P. denisonii)/` to match all the non-whitespace sequences AND sequence "P. denisonii"

To exclude comma, quote and full-stop and other characters just substitute \S with a negative regexp character list `[^...]`:

`/([^\s,\.\"]+)|(P. denisonii)/` matches all the sequences that do not contain whitespace (`\s`), comma, quote and dot (`\.`)

*Edit:* to match a generic genus name (NOTE: I've altered your text to test the code better including quote and a bogus genus name)

```
$text = "Initially considered \"endemic\" to the Chalakudy River system in Kerala state, southern India, but now recognised to have a wider distribution in surrounding drainages including the Periyar, Manimala, and Pamba river though the Manimala data may be questionable given it seems to be the type locality of P. denisonii.

This is a bogus genus name, A. testii.

In the Achankovil River basin it occurs sympatrically, and sometimes syntopically, with P. denisonii.

Wild stocks may have dwindled by as much as 50% in the last 15 years or so with collection for the aquarium trade largely held responsible although habitats are also being degraded by pollution from agricultural and domestic sources, plus destructive fishing methods involving explosives or organic toxins.";


preg_match_all("/([A-Z]\. [a-z]+)|([^\s,\.\"]+)/", $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

NOTE: the array you should pick is `$matches[0]`, not `$matches`

Comment: Hi Cranio - I'll expand my OP to explain, but it isn't just `P. denisonii` I want to split, it's any species reference which take the format Genus (abbreviated to G.) species, such as `A. panduro`, `S. daemon` etc.

Comment: Hi mate - thanks for that. For some reason, I'm getting these entries: `[55] => syntopically`, `[56] => with P`, `[57] => denisonii` rather than `P. denisonii` as an entry.

Comment: Strange, the code I posted works well with my test string. Are you using the very same regexp?

Comment: Yeah, I copied and pasted your `preg_match_all` identically, and simply replaced `$text` with my `$value`.

Comment: Can you post here (or in pastebin or another place) your $value to crosscheck?

Comment: It's exactly what I posted in my OP, and what you've used, minus the additional text you included.